# How to assign File/Folder path to a Variable in Terminal

Tags: command-line, directory, environment-variables

Say I have the following path:

```
/home/$USER/Downloads/My Folder
```

I tried to assign the above given File-Path to a variable `FILE_NAME` as follows,

```
FILE_NAME=/home/$USER/Downloads/My Folder
$FILE_NAME
```

The output was:

```
bash: /home/$USER/Downloads/My :No such file or directory
```

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use quotes if the path contains space characters:

```
FILE_NAME="/home/$USER/Downloads/My Folder"
```

Comment: I tried giving the file name within quotes but the error still remains.

Comment: @logamadi The error isn't an issue *setting* the variable, it's from how you're calling it. If you want to echo the content of the variable, run `echo $FILE_NAME`. What you were doing is just trying to execute it. And if it's still telling you it doesn't exist, it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Rmano,@Oli
The commands "ls" and "cd" work when we wrap the User-defined variable within quotes like :cd "$FILE_NAME" (or) ls "$FILE_NAME"
Credit to george Barbaz

Answer (score 3):

The issue is the embedded blank in the name. The simplest way to resolve this issue is to enclose the full path string with quotes (i.e. `FILE_NAME="/home/${USER}/Downloads/My Folder"`
The reason to use `"` in your case is because of your use of $USER which requires a substitution, with `'` this would not occur.

A secondary question is how are you going to use the variable.
In your example... I would assume that you dropped the cd from the command
however ... to use the variable ... you should probably also use " around its use

so ... my guess at your use ... cd "$FILE_NAME"

Comment: Error still persists

Comment: see further edit of my msg ... the command line you are using would try to execute "$FILE_NAME"